# SQLite and foreign keys: bad examples from documentation don't fail

Tags: sqlite

I am looking at the examples from [https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) and try to reproduce them. This is what I get.

```
SQLite version 3.11.1 2016-03-03 16:17:53
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys; -- check that it registered
1
sqlite> CREATE TABLE parent(a PRIMARY KEY, b UNIQUE, c, d, e, f);
sqlite> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i1 ON parent(c, d);
sqlite> CREATE INDEX i2 ON parent(e);
sqlite> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX i3 ON parent(f COLLATE nocase);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE child1(f, g REFERENCES parent(a));
sqlite> CREATE TABLE child2(h, i REFERENCES parent(b));
sqlite> CREATE TABLE child3(j, k, FOREIGN KEY(j, k) REFERENCES parent(c, d));
sqlite> CREATE TABLE child4(l, m REFERENCES parent(e)); -- Error?
sqlite> CREATE TABLE child5(n, o REFERENCES parent(f)); -- Error?
sqlite> CREATE TABLE child6(p, q, FOREIGN KEY(p, q) REFERENCES parent(b, c)); -- Error?
sqlite> CREATE TABLE child7(r REFERENCES parent(c)); -- Error?
sqlite> select * from sqlite_master where type='table';
table|parent|parent|2|CREATE TABLE parent(a PRIMARY KEY, b UNIQUE, c, d, e, f)
table|child1|child1|8|CREATE TABLE child1(f, g REFERENCES parent(a))
table|child2|child2|9|CREATE TABLE child2(h, i REFERENCES parent(b))
table|child3|child3|10|CREATE TABLE child3(j, k, FOREIGN KEY(j, k) REFERENCES parent(c, d))
table|child4|child4|11|CREATE TABLE child4(l, m REFERENCES parent(e))
table|child5|child5|12|CREATE TABLE child5(n, o REFERENCES parent(f))
table|child6|child6|13|CREATE TABLE child6(p, q, FOREIGN KEY(p, q) REFERENCES parent(b, c))
table|child7|child7|14|CREATE TABLE child7(r REFERENCES parent(c))
```

The examples that should fail (child 4 to 7) don't, at least at table creation. However the documentation implies that it should. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation you linked to](http://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) says:

> If the database schema contains foreign key errors that require looking at more than one table definition to identify, then those errors are not detected when the tables are created. Instead, such errors prevent the application from preparing SQL statements that modify the content of the child or parent tables in ways that use the foreign keys.

Comment: What would you say are "foreign key errors that require looking at more than one table definition to identify"? What would be foreign key errors that do not need to look at more than one table?